# How does an absolutely positioned div influence its children?

Tags: html, css, positioning

We're in the process of building a single page web app with multiple sections that the user can interact with. 
I currently need to build the main layout of the app which should divide the page into those separate sections. **I have no control over the inner content that will be added to each section.**

Each section should be able to be enlarged by the user and push the other sections out of the view area. Because of this, I am thinking of using absolute positioning for each section in order to position them correctly and allow for changing the position on the view easily.

The ideal would be if someone could develop the inner content of each section as if he is developing on his own page. So my concern is - how does absolutely positioning a parent div affect the children elements that will be added?

Comment: Did you come up with a solution? Please post if you did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting this to follow up on the findings.

The main issue is that positioning an element as non-static does have immediate affect on any children that are positioned as absolute.

This is because the parent element would become these children's containing block, as opposed to if it was static. In the latter case, the children's containing block would be the first ancestor with a position other than static. See [Absolute positioning](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-positioning/#absolute-positioning) & [Definition of containing block](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-positioning/#containing-block0) (thanks to @Edouard Lopez). Because of this any positioning of children elements would be in relation to the absolute parent.

Also, as @fredsbend described, the absolute positioned div element will expand according to the width of its contained elements, not according to its container, which would be the case for a static positioned div. This will also affect the children if they don't have an explicit width set.

Answer (score 2):

I reckon the property `position: absolute|relative|...` is here to indicate how the described element behave relatively to its parents/ancestors, not how its children will behave.

If you use an absolute positioning on each section, they will all be out of the normal flow. This mean you will have to re-create the –normal– flow-mechanism. I recommend you to read the section [Comparison of normal flow, floats, and positioning](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-positioning/#comparison)

Comment: thanks for the link. I would say that positioning an element describes its behavior relative to its normal flow, not always relative to its parent/ancestors. However, positioning an element as non-static does have immediate affect on any children that are positioned as absolute because that element would become these children's containing block. I'm looking for any other effects that could happen.

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to what the name implies, absolute positioned elements will expand or contract with the content within them so long as you do not specify a width or height. http://jsfiddle.net/M3CZg/

```
#abs1 {
position:absolute;
top:0;
}
#abs2 {
position:absolute;
top:50px;
width: 400px;
}

<div id="abs1"></div>
<div id="abs2"></div>
```

Fill those two divs with any content and they will expand accordingly.

For what you are saying with the user manipulated divs, you can use a min-width and min-height and also max-width and max-height to keep the expansion within a range. This would also require overflow:hidden in case content is bigger then max properties. http://jsfiddle.net/M3CZg/3/ Play around with that and move the window to see how the divs flex.